# Setting a signed cookie for unit tests

Tags: django

In writing a unit test for my function, I am creating a request using the RequestFactory (*my function takes a request as a parameter - it's called from a view*)

```
factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.get('/')
```

Before I feed this request to my view for testing, I need to put a signed cookie in it (*the function expects it in incoming requests*).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up signing and assigning the cookie like this (*basically copied the signing logic from HttpResponse*)

```
from django.core import signing

signedValue = signing.get_cookie_signer(salt=key + salt).sign(value)
request.COOKIES[key]=signedValue
```